# Combinatorics Pigeonhole Problem find Max Number of Possible Different Colors such that each Sub-Group of Size 9 from 60 Contains 3 Same-Color Balls

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

**Let a box contain 60 colored balls. In each group of 9 balls, at least 3 of them are the same color.**

**What is the maximal number of possible colors which will allow the above condition to be true?**

I have tried to think of a solution in the following way - if I find the minimal number of colors for which the condition is **not** true and subtract 1, I'll get the maximal number for which it is true.

The minimal number of colors for which the condition is not true will satisfy the following condition - there will be at least 1 group in which there will be balls of at least 8 different colors.

Is this the correct approach? If so, how do I continue from here?

Comment: Your logic is correct! Though, I don't really get what you mean with your second-last paragraph. Here's my approach: if there are $n$ colors and at most 2 balls of each color in a group, that means there are at most $2n$ balls in the group, right? So, if $n=5$ and the group has 10 balls, we can perfectly form 2 balls/color. But what if we add one more ball? That one extra ball will **ruin everything**. Whichever color it is, it'll make 3 balls have the same color. So, with the same reasoning, we can say that for a group of 9 balls, there are at most 4 colors. 

Comment: My comment doesn't apply here, actually (since you can control the number of balls of each color). David Chew's answer is correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach may work, I haven't tried it, but I find another approach is more straightforward:

You can have $7$ colors, as you can choose $54$ of one and $6$ of the others, so every set will have $3$ of that first color. You can't have $8$ colors, as then you can pick a group with one of each of them, and it would have $8$ different, so couldn't have $3$ of one.